# JavaFX. Как запретить enter в TextArea

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

Сделал, чтобы на новую строку можно было перейти, нажав `Ctrl+Enter`, а `Enter` будет служить для отправки сообщения.
Проблема в том, что даже перехватывая событие нажатия `Enter`, новая строка все равно проставляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается все просто. Раз enter это клавиша для отправки сообщения, то просто отправляем его и очищаем поле)))